# How to exclude string from Font-Awesome in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, icons, font-awesome

How can i exclude a string from formatting into a Font-Awesome Icon?

In my case, I have a Label in XAML, which has a Text Binding to a string. The Font-Family of this Label is Font-Awesome. In my C# Code, the string looks like this:

```
CurrentSorting = "Date \xf062";
```

The Output looks like this:

> D@e (and the \xf062 Icon)

However I want the output to be like this:

> Date (and the \xf062 Icon)

How can I achieve this?

[EDIT]

My Label in XAML:

```
<Label 
     Margin="10,0,0,0"
     TextColor="#FF9340"
     Text="{Binding CurrentSorting}"
     FontFamily="{StaticResource Font-Awesome}"
     HeightRequest="40"
     VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
```

C# Code:

```
case "4":
                {
                    CurrentSorting = "Date \xf062";
                    Entries = new ObservableCollection<Entry>(Entries.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList());
                    break;
                }
```

ResourceDictionary:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="Font-Awesome">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Font-Awesome.ttf#Font-Awesome" />
            <!--<On Platform="iOS" Value="Raleway-SemiBold" />-->
</OnPlatform>
```

Output on my phone:
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I've created a test project with a Font-Awesome ttf font, and have achieved a label with 'Date' and then the icon displaying. Can you post your page's XAML and where you're defining the Label's FontFamily? Note I'm using ttf so the icon is define as &#062; rather than \xf062, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Is there any other code associated with this? Because converting `at` to `@` is not default behavior.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thanks for the quick responses. I added more information on my question.

Comment: @JamesLavery Thanks for the quick responses. I added more information on my question.

Comment: Are you using a ttf or otf font? Can you please post a screenshot of the resulting output?

Comment: Using a Property like you are, I still can't reproduce this. I get 'Date (smiley face)' when I return "Date \xf118" from my CurrentSorting property.

Comment: That is strange. However, I added a screenshot. I am using a ttf font at the moment.

Comment: Here is an article for reference .(https://www.wintellect.com/using-fontawesome5-xamarin-forms/) Maybe missing steps in project. @RobertHaslinger

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: @JamesLavery which ttf are you using when you try to reproduce? I found more than one and I think that I am simply using the wrong one.

Comment: I'm using fa-regular-400.ttf. I think this must be different to yours, because \xf062 doesn't give me an up arrow - it give me a > sign.

Comment: @JamesLavery Oh, I have already tried that font but since it does not have that up arrow button I dumped it. Maybe I just have to mess with 2 or 3 Labels which have different fonts. Personally I don't like that solution but it's the only one working at the moment.

Comment: @RobertHaslinger If solved it , you can post an answer.If have better solution, will share here later.